# How to model concurrency in unit tests?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, concurrency

I'm pretty new to unit testing and currently experimenting a bit with Visual Studio's testing tools.

My question is how to define assertions about *concurrent behaviour* in these tests. E.g. given a class `BoundedChan<T>` implementing a bounded channel, how can I specify tests like

1. "`channel.Send` will not block" or
2. "If the channel's capacity is exceeded, `channel.Send` will block until a value is read"

Is there an elegant solution to write these assertions?

Comment: I'm not sure there are any precise duplicates (though this one is close: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314580/how-do-i-perform-a-unit-test-using-threads), but there's quite a bit of good SO material on this. I've listed some of the better discussions in my response here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520539/how-to-prove-that-multithreading-is-working/1520619#1520619.

Comment: @Jeff: Why don't you post this as an answer - Looks quite useful to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, concurrency is still an area of unit testing that is challenging to structure easily. It's not a simple problem, and still requires that you implement some of your own synchronization and concurrency logic in the test.

For the example you provide, it may be impossible to write a test that *conclusively* demonstrates that a method will or won't block under certain conditions. You may be able to achieve some level of confidence by first creating worst-case circumstances where you would expect the blocking behavior - and then write tests to determine if that occurs or not.

Here's a [blog article](https://web.archive.org/web/20091111102407/http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/danbarvitsky/archive/2009/06/12/techniques-for-testing-concurrent-code-in-nunit.aspx) that discusses the topic; it focuses on NUnit.

Comment: Link is dead, but Wayback Machine has your back. Original Dan Barvitsky article: https://web.archive.org/web/20140822013404/http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/danbarvitsky/archive/2009/06/12/techniques-for-testing-concurrent-code-in-nunit.aspx . His follow up post: https://web.archive.org/web/20100526080326/http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/danbarvitsky/archive/2009/06/15/my-solution-for-unit-testing-concurrent-code-in-nunit.aspx .

Answer (score 6):

This question could lead to enough content to fill a book.

In general, I would not recommend adding unit tests to your classes for concurrent scenarios.  With practice I think you'll learn that automated unit tests have one or several "sweet spots" -- and that focusing your efforts in these areas (and using other practices in other areas) yields better ROI.

But your class seems to be *about* concurrency (can't tell for certain based on info provided), and therefore this could be a case where you really want a concurrency-simulating test.

You can (as far as I know) start up multiple threads in a unit test if you wish.  But there may be a simpler way.  Consider leveraging the [Compose Method](http://www.industriallogic.com/xp/refactoring/composeMethod.html) pattern.  While we're on the subject -- this pattern is pretty critical to effective unit tests over all, not just with concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a helper that can start a bunch of threads to execute concurrent actions. The helper provides synchronization primitives and logging mechanisms. 
It can be used in conjunction with any unit test framework. Here is a code fragment from a unit test:

```
[Test]
public void TwoCodeBlocksInParallelTest()
{
    // This static method runs the provided Action delegates in parallel using threads
    CTestHelper.Run(
        c =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000); // Here should be the code to provide something 
                CTestHelper.AddSequenceStep("Provide"); // We record a sequence step for the expectations after the test
                CTestHelper.SetEvent();
            },
        c =>
            {
                CTestHelper.WaitEvent(); // We wait until we can consume what is provided
                CTestHelper.AddSequenceStep("Consume"); // We record a sequence step for the expectations after the test
            },
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)); // This is a timeout parameter, if the threads are deadlocked or take too long, the threads are terminated and a timeout exception is thrown 

    // After Run() completes we can analyze if the recorded sequence steps are in the correct order
    Expect(CTestHelper.GetSequence(), Is.EqualTo(new[] { "Provide", "Consume" }));
}
```

It can be used to test client/server or synchronization in components or simply run a thread with a timeout. I'll continue to improve this in the next weeks. Here is the project page:
[Concurrency Testing Helper](http://www.crawler-lib.net/crawler-lib-concurrency-testing)