# Automated .NET tool to check for thread safety?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

Is there any automated tool to check C# .NET code for thread safety?

p.s. It doesn't have to be perfect, but it should check for the obvious things that can be checked at compile time.

Comment: Define "thread safety". And I really doubt a tool will be useful for that.

Comment: Almost certainly a duplicate question, but: CHESS http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/b23f8dc3-bb73-498f-bd85-1de121672e69/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955561/how-to-test-for-thread-safety ?

Comment: Scratch "at compile time" off your list of requirements, that magic doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you name one of the "obvious things that can be checked at compile time" and what relationship they have to "thread safety"? For example: it would be straightforward to write a tool that detects usages of "lock(this)" at compile time. Locking "this" is a *bad programming practice* but that does not necessarily make it *thread-unsafe*. What's an example of something that is both "unsafe" and detectable at compile time?

Comment: Something it might check is modifying a shared collection within two different public methods that is known to be unsafe.  Seems like an obvious thread-safety problem.  Another example of a problem it could detect is reading and modifying a shared 64-bit value within two different internal or public methods of a class.  There's numerous ways to accidentally write unsafe code.  The tool could perhaps be told which methods are allowed to be executed from multiple threads and then conduct its static analysis accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I've seen is TypeMock's racer.  It isn't compile time, but it can make some thread bugs (like deadlocking) possible to test.