# Testing concurrent data structure

Tags: c++, testing, concurrency

What are some methods for testing concurrent data structures to make sure the data structs behave correctly when accessed from multiple threads ?

Comment: Use a library that other people have validated for you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit testing real-time / concurrent software](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733484/unit-testing-real-time-concurrent-software)

Comment: Further candidates: [Guidelines for testing multithreaded code or ensuring that code is thread-safe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444452/guidelines-for-testing-multithreaded-code-or-ensuring-that-code-is-thread-safe) and [Unit Testing Concurrent Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035890/unit-testing-concurrent-code). These all are in the *Related* list on the right.

Comment: Difference is that this question deals with a single data structure (with well defined interface) and the discussion is not limited to just unittest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the other answers have focused on actually testing the code by putting it through its paces and actually running it in one form or another or politely saying "don't do it yourself, use an existing library".

This is great and all, but IMO, the most important (practical tests are important too) test is to look at the code line by line and for **every** line of code ask "what happens if I get interrupted by another thread here?" Imagine another thread, running just about any of the other lines/functions during this interruption. Do things still stay consistent? When competing for resources, does the other thread[s] block or spin?

This is what we did in school when learning about concurrency and it is a surprisingly effective approach. Bottom line, I feel that taking the time to prove to yourself that things are consistent and work as expected in all states is the first technique you should use when dealing with this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I normally test these kinds of things by interjecting `sleep()` calls at appropriate places in the distributed threads/processes.

For instance, to test a lock, put `sleep(2)` in all your threads at the point of contention, and spawn two threads roughly 1 second apart. The first one should obtain the lock, and the second should have to wait for it.

Most race conditions can be tested by extending this method, but if your system has too many components it may be difficult or impossible to know every possible condition that needs to be tested.

Comment: This is by far the best answer in practice, IME.

Answer (score 1):

Concurrent systems are probabilistic and errors are often difficult to replicate. Therefore you need to run various input/output cases, each tested over time (hours, days, etc) in order to detect possible errors.

Tests for concurrent data structure involves examining the container's state before and after expected events such as insert and delete.

Answer (score 1):

Use a pre-existing, pre-tested library that meets your needs if possible.

Make sure that the code has appropriate self-consistency checks (preferably fast sanity checks), and run your code on as many different types of hardware as possible to help narrow down interesting timing problems.

Have multiple people peer review the code, preferably without a pre-explanation of how it's supposed to work. That way they have to grok the code which should help catch more bugs.

Set up a bunch of threads that do nothing but random operations on the data structures and check for consistency at some rate.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the assumption that your calls to access/modify data are not thread safe and use locks to ensure only a single thread can access/modify any part of the data at a time.  Only after you can prove to yourself that a specific type of access is safe outside of the lock by multiple threads at once should you move that code outside of the lock.

Assume worst case scenarios, e.g. that your code will stop right in the middle of some pointer manipulation or another critical point, and that another thread will encounter that data in mid-transition.  If that would have a bad result, leave it within the lock.

Comment: The downside is that being conservative with locking decreases performance, and locking too much code defeats the point of multi-threading.

Comment: @kefeizhou: Is it helpful to have fast code that produces the wrong result?

Comment: @kefeizhou: Then just go through your code and white-box test all the accesses and modifications.  Don't assume everything is ok if you run your code a bunch of times and it doesn't break.  You'll end up with crashes and data corruption when you move to another system to encounter a heavy load that will be next to impossible to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Run your concurrent threads for one or a few days and look what happens. (Sounds strange, but finding out race conditions is such a complex topic that simply trying it is the best approach).