# fail to update a property in multi-threaded code

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, thread-safety

I try to write this unit-test

```
@Test
public void setUserNamePropertyFromMultiThreadsUpdatesCorrectly() throws Exception {
    boolean oldVal = UsersConfig.s.NO_DB_MODE;
        final List<String> lastName = new ArrayList<String>();
        UsersConfig.s.NO_DB_MODE = true;

        String user1 = testUtils.generateUserName();
        final Long createdId = testUtils.createUserWithProperties(ImmutableMap.of("username", user1, "A", "A1",
                "isStaff", "true"));

        List<Callable<Void>> callables = new ArrayList<Callable<Void>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            callables.add(new Callable<Void>() {
                @Override
                public Void call() throws Exception {
                    String user2 = testUtils.generateUserName();
                    boolean isSuccess = usersServerAccess.setProperties(createdId,
                            ImmutableMap.of("isStaff", "dont_know", "username", user2),
                            1, "test set", someTimeOut);
                    assertTrue(isSuccess);

                    synchronized (lastName) {
                        lastName.add(user2);
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            });

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        try {
            executorService.invokeAll(callables);
            executorService.shutdown();
            executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        User returnedUser = usersServerAccess.getUser(createdId, "get test", someTimeOut);
        assertThat(returnedUser.getProperty("username"), equalTo(lastName.get(0)));
        assertThat(returnedUser.getProperty("A"), equalTo("A1"));
        assertThat(returnedUser.getProperty("isStaff"), equalTo("dont_know"));
}
```

however my test fails.

The username is not changed.
would you add "sleep" ? something else?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly consider a different testing approach. It appears that you are trying to test your usersServerAccess class - focus on an individual unit test for this class (possibly using a mocking framework such as [Mockito](http://mockito.org/)). With this unit test, you can be sure that your code in that class is working as expected.

What you're trying to do here looks like a multithreaded integration test, which is tricky at the best of times (@see [Unit testing a multithreaded application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111676/unit-testing-a-multithreaded-application)). How does this code fit into the framework of your application? Maybe consider an end to end testing framework like [JBehave](http://jbehave.org/) or [Cucumber](https://cucumber.io/).