# Frameworks for Unittests for Multithreading in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, concurrency

Which frameworks would you recommend for writing unit tests for multithreading code in Java? Like, for example, when you have a program that is supposed to execute a bunch of threads with several allowed paths of executions and certain excluded paths (like "executable unit 1, 2 and 3 can run in parallel, at least two should be run in parallel, and 4 always has to run after 3").

Answer (score 3):

I suggest reading about [JUnit `@Rule`](http://blog.mycila.com/2009/11/writing-your-own-junit-extensions-using.html) to use them for concurrency tests.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [ContiPerf2](http://databene.org/contiperf) since it is a very easy to use framework. Although I do not think it will provide the possibility to declare execution pathes or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use parametrized JUnit tests, as described here: http://junit.org/junit/javadoc/4.5/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html

But you will need to program thread logic yourself, for example by using different thread pools.

You can take a look at pathfinder (http://javapathfinder.sourceforge.net/) if you want to prove that your code is thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

This thread describes some general approaches to testing concurrent code.

[Designing a Test class for a custom Barrier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418373/designing-a-test-class-for-a-custom-barrier/4427499#4427499)

For specific frameworks,  [tempus-fugit](http://tempusfugitlibrary.org) has some JUnit [rules to run things in parallel](http://tempusfugitlibrary.org/documentation/junit/parallel/) but as suggested above, you're tests will likely have to include more logic.