# Logging statement causes deadlock in simple Java code?

Tags: java, logging, concurrency, licensing, deadlock

I'm having a weird problem with some fairly simple Java code.

I have a class `LicenseManager`, which controls the licensing of a program, and can be controlled dynamically (new licenses can be issued on demand, etc). `LicenseManager` of course needs to be thread safe, as such, it uses a big lock. However it has one more lock that it uses around controlling apples, which I believe is somehow involved in this deadlock, but I can't really see how. The program also installs a logging handler to support an enterprise logging feature.

Just looking at the code of `LicenseManager` by itself, I can't see a single issue in it.

```
import java.util.logging.*;

public class Main {
    public static final LicenseManager licenseManager = new LicenseManager();

    static class LicenseManager {
        private static final Logger logger =
                Logger.getLogger(LicenseManager.class.getName());

        class InsufficientApplesException extends RuntimeException {};
        class InsufficientPiesException extends RuntimeException {};

        private int apples = 10;
        private int pies = 10;
        private boolean enterpriseLoggingEnabled = true;

        // Apples have high contention; so they get their own lock.
        private final Object appleLock = new Object();

        void useApple() {
            checkExpired();
            synchronized (appleLock) {
                logger.info("Using apple. Apples left: " + apples);
                if (apples == 0) throw new InsufficientApplesException();
                apples--;
            }
        }

        /* Examples. There are lots of other operations like this
         * on LicenseManager. We don't have time to prove that
         * they are commutative, so we just use the main object lock
         * around them all. The exception is when we find one with high
         * contention, for example apples. */
        synchronized void usePear() {checkExpired(); /*...*/}
        synchronized void checkExpired() {}

        synchronized void usePie() {
            checkExpired();
            logger.info("Using pie. Pies left: " + pies);
            if (pies == 0) throw new InsufficientPiesException();
            boolean reallyCanUsePie = true; // do expensive pie computation
            if (reallyCanUsePie) {
                useApple(); /* using a pie requires an apple.
                             * TODO: stop putting apples in the pumpkin pie */
                pies--;
            }
        }

        synchronized boolean isEnterpriseLoggingEnabled() {
            return enterpriseLoggingEnabled;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Install enterprise log handler on the root logger
        Logger.getLogger("").addHandler(new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void publish(LogRecord lr) {
                if (licenseManager.isEnterpriseLoggingEnabled())
                    System.out.println("ENTERPRISE ALERT! [" 
                            + lr.getLevel() + "] " + lr.getMessage());
            }
            @Override public void flush() {}
            @Override public void close() throws SecurityException {}
        });

        // Simulate fat user
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    licenseManager.usePie();
                }
            }
        }.start();

        // Simulate fat albeit healthy user
        while (true) {
            licenseManager.useApple();
        }
    }
}
```

And when I run it:

```
$ java Main
Apr 25, 2013 3:23:19 PM Main$LicenseManager useApple
INFO: Using apple. Apples left: 10
Apr 25, 2013 3:23:19 PM Main$LicenseManager usePie
INFO: Using pie. Pies left: 10
ENTERPRISE ALERT! [INFO] Using pie. Pies left: 10
```

You'd expect the pie eaters to both die from running out of pies, but instead both threads deadlock.

Interestingly, removing the logging line in `useApple` (`logger.info("Using apple. Apples left: " + apples);`) makes the deadlock not happen (you don't see the log spammed with "using pie", because all the apples so happened to be gone before any pie could be used):

```
$ java Main
Exception in thread "main" Main$LicenseManager$InsufficientApplesException
    at Main$LicenseManager.useApple(Main.java:24)
    at Main.main(Main.java:79)
Apr 25, 2013 3:23:42 PM Main$LicenseManager usePie
INFO: Using pie. Pies left: 10
ENTERPRISE ALERT! [INFO] Using pie. Pies left: 10
Exception in thread "Thread-1" Main$LicenseManager$InsufficientApplesException
    at Main$LicenseManager.useApple(Main.java:24)
    at Main$LicenseManager.usePie(Main.java:43)
    at Main$2.run(Main.java:72)
```

Why? How can I fix this without removing the logging?

Comment: Do they really deadlock or do they spin?  You've seen deadlock in the stacks traces?

Comment: Have you tried inserting a little `Thread.sleep()` in your `while(true)`s ?

Comment: FYI: The logger may have a synchronized `PrintStream` under the covers which would change the synchronization pattern of your program.

Comment: If there is a deadlock then somewhere inside of the `synchronized (appleLock)` you must lock your `Main` class with a call to a `synchronized static` method.  Any idea if that is being done?

Comment: did you try some thread monitoring from inside visualvm to see which thread holds which monitor/lock?

Comment: @Gray, I assume it's a deadlock because the VM is using no CPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `log.info()` calls ends up in the `Handler`'s `publish()` method where `licenseManager.isEnterpriseLoggingEnabled()` needs a lock on the `licenseManager`.

So this code can't complete:

```
   synchronized (appleLock) {
       //this line requires a lock on license manager, and this lock is not 
       //available because is hold by the other thread waiting to get the appleLock
       logger.info("Using apple. Apples left: " + apples);

       if (apples == 0) throw new InsufficientApplesException();
       apples--;
  }
```

One easy way to get rid of the deadlock is to remove the synchronization on `isEnterpriseLoggingEnabled()` method. It doesn't seem to be needed as `enterpriseLoggingEnabled` property is readonly.

Comment: wait... so the log handler callback is done on the same thread as the `log.info()` call?!?

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense, why wasting a thread or making a context switch just this ...

Comment: Yep, seems they are in the same thread: https://ideone.com/Z6Dqgr . I was thinking the logging stuff in Java has one thread with a queue that all logs go to, and then the handlers would be ran in that one thread. I guess I thought this because the docs for `Logger` say it's thread safe. Is it documented somewhere whether the handlers are called in the same thread? How can I fix my code without removing the logging?

Comment: `isEnterpriseLoggingEnabled` needs a lock because it's called by multiple threads. I'd like to not remove/split any more locks because it would make the code harder to reason about (The whole reason this problem happened in the first place was because I split the big lock into two locks)

Comment: Yes, but the value of `enterpriseLoggingEnabled` is always true, you never change it at runtime. No need for synchronization in this case.

Comment: Yeah I didn't post the full code, but either way it would be a data race unless that variable was final (example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178020/uninitialized-object-leaked-to-another-thread-despite-no-code-explicitly-leaking). I guess I could just make it always return true, or give it its own lock.

Answer (score 2):

They get into a deadlock because the main thread (the one eating apples) owns the `appleLock` and is trying to access the `synchronized isEnterpriseLoggingEnabled()` method and the child thread (the one eating pies) owns the `licenseManager` object and calls `useApple()` inside of `usePie()` (and thus needs `appleLock`).

The deadlock doesn't happen without the `Logger` statement because it no longer has to call a synchronized method within `licenseManager` after taking the `appleLock`

You can probably fix this by making `isEnterpriseLoggingEnabled` not `synchronized`

Comment: `useApple` only accesses the `licenseManager` lock via `checkExpired()`, then **releases** it, then gets `appleLock`, wherein it doesn't do anything that locks `licenseManager`.

Comment: @Dog I tested this using a debugger. I am 100% sure my answer is what happens.

Comment: How can deadlock happen if there is no logging in `useApple`? I think the deadlock is caused by the logging in `useApple`, since it calls the handler which calls back `isEnterpriseLoggingEnabled`, which makes it try to get both locks at once.

Comment: Oh I didn't notice your edit. Any clue how to fix this without removing the logging?

Answer (score 1):

Why this happens:

you have a lot of synchronized methods. but they all synchronize on one monitor - youк instance of Main, so you deadlock yourself by calling 2 of the methods simultaneously. To sort it all out you have to make separate monitors (lock objects) for different parts of your code. You do have separate lock for apples (`appleLock`), but still synchronize above it on `Main instance` for whatever reason.

Why you don't need sync on `isEnterpriseLoggingEnabled()`:

Despite having contention, if you do not set it like `enterpriseLoggingEnabled=!enterpriseLoggingEnabled;`, it is ok to not sync. You just have to update the value on read. To do it, make enterpriseLoggingEnabled `volatile`. This should eliminate unnecessary lock and the whole lock problem. If you really need the lock here or in another method that contents with the aplle consumers, make a separate lock for it. Maybe a `ReentrantLock`.