# Testing concurrency features

Tags: ruby, testing, concurrency

How would you test Ruby code that has some concurrency features? For instance, let's assume I have a synchronization mechanism that is expected to prevent deadlocks. Is there a viable way to test what it really does? Could controlled execution in fibers be the way forward?

Comment: This is a difficult problem even in languages where the community has more of an emphasis on concurrency than the Ruby community has. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159/how-should-i-unit-test-threaded-code

Comment: Any chance you could post some code, even pseudo codeE?  This is hard to answer generically, and it's also hard to know what aspects of your code you wish to test.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem and have implemented a simple gem for synchronizing subprocesses using breakpoints: http://github.com/remen/fork_break

I've also documented an advanced usage scenario for rails3 at http://www.hairoftheyak.com/testing-concurrency-in-rails/

Answer (score 2):

I needed to make sure a gem (`redis-native_hash`) I authored could handle concurrent writes to the same Redis hash, detect the race condition, and elegantly recover. I found that to test this I didn't need to use threads at all.

```
it "should respect changes made since last read from redis" do
  concurrent_edit = Redis::NativeHash.find :test => @hash.key
  concurrent_edit["foo"] = "race value"
  concurrent_edit.save
  @hash["yin"] = "yang"
  @hash["foo"] = "bad value"
  @hash.save
  hash = Redis::NativeHash.find :test => @hash.key
  hash["foo"].should == "race value"
  hash["yin"].should == "yang"
end
```

In this test case I just instantiated another object which represents the concurrent edit of the Redis hash, had it make a change, then make sure saving the already-existing object pointing to the same hash respected those changes.

Not all problems involving concurrency can be tested without actually USING concurrency, but in this case it was possible. You may want to try looking for something similar to test your concurrency solutions. If its possible its definitely the easier route to go.

Comment: I see your point. This is an elegant workaround for specific cases.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely a difficult problem.  I started writing my test using threads, and realized that they way the code I was testing was implemented, I needed the Process IDs (PID) to actually be different.  Threads run using the same PID as the process that kicked off the Thread.  Lesson learned.

It was at that point I started exploring forks, and came across this Stack Overflow thread, and played with fork_break.  Pretty cool, and easy to set up.  Though I didn't need the breakpoints for what I was doing, I just wanted processes to run through concurrently, using breakpoints could be very useful in the future.  The problem I ran into was that I kept getting an EOFError and I didn't know why.  So I started implementing forking myself, instead of going through fork_break, and found out it was that an exception was happening in the code under test.  Sad that the stack trace was hidden from me by the EOFError, though I understand that the child process ended abruptly and that's kinda how it goes.

The next problem I came across was with the DatabaseCleaner.  No matter which strategy it used (truncation, or transaction), the child process's data was truncated/rolled back when the child process finished, so the data that was inserted by child processes was gone and the parent process couldn't select and verify that it was correct.

After banging my head on that and trying many other unsuccessful things, I came across this post http://makandracards.com/makandra/556-test-concurrent-ruby-code which was almost exactly what I was already doing, with one little addition.  Calling "Process.exit!" at the end of the fork.  My best guess (based on my fairly limited understanding of forking) is that this causes the process to end abruptly enough that it completely bypasses any type of database cleanup when the child process ends.  So my parent process, the actual test, can continue and verify the data it needs to verify.  Then during the normal after hooks of the test (in this case cucumber, but could easily be rspec too), the database cleaner kicks in and cleans up data as it normally would for a test.

So, just thought I'd share some of my own lessons learned in this discusson of how to test concurrent features.