# Mocking System.Threading.Thread in .NET

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

My issue is - I have a class that has a `System.Threading.Thread` dependancy, and it will `Start()` the Thread once a certain condition is met.  I am having an issue Mocking a `System.Threading.Thread`.

I generally use **Moq** for mock objects, but I can't Mock a `Thread` (because it is sealed).

I do realize I could write some wrapper that contains a Thread, then mock that wrapper - but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: Consider using a `Task` instead.

Answer (score 3):

There's been a couple questions already posted attempting to cover this with a good answer, like this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159/how-should-i-unit-test-threaded-code).  For the TLDR;  The problem space is really that your taking your code which is asynchronous and trying to adapt it to a mocking framework and unit test, which is synchronous.  Long story short, there's not a good solution to this, but if you follow the link I believe there are some shady work-arounds. Good luck

Comment: I really just trying to Mock the actual Thread object - not the asynchronous logic that will end up being called.  The real crux of the issue is I want to mock `Thread` to I can call `myTrhead.Start()`