# Using easymock in multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, testing, easymock

I want to test that some method would be recalled on failing. Calling executed in separate thread. So I write code like this

```
final Foo mock = createStrictMock(Foo.class);

mock.bar();
expectLastCall().andThrow(new RuntimeException("TEST EXCEPTION"));
mock.bar();
replay(mock);

doStuff();
sleepSomeTime(); //Pretty dirty. But I need to test it in multithreading.
verify(mock);
```

And test passed. But I did not implement recall yet.

To make test fail, I replaced

```
 mock.bar();
 expectLastCall().andThrow(new RuntimeException("TEST EXCEPTION"));
```

with

```
 mock.bar();
 expectLastCall().andAnswer(new IAnswer<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void answer() throws Throwable {
            sleepSomeTime();
            throw new RuntimeException("TEST EXCEPTION");
        }
    });
```

But I don't like adding  sleepSomeTime  all around my tests. Beside that, I don't actually understand while it helps in this particular case. 
So,

Why adding delay helped?

What the right way to do such stuff?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My approach has been to use locks. There isn't quite enough info in your post to show something definitive, but it'd probably look something like this:

```
final Lock lock = new Lock();
lock.lock();
expectLastCall().andAnswer(new IAnswer<Void>() {
    @Override public Void answer() throws Throwable {
        lock.unlock();
        throw new RuntimeException("TEST EXCEPTION");
    }
});     
doStuff();
lock.lock();
verify(mock);
```

The gist here is the second lock() invocation is blocked until the unlock in your mock frees up the lock.

Comment: It's the best answer. But I believe this should be done without locks.

Comment: Depending on your code, you can hook in callbacks so your verification methods are done in a callback that you tickle in the last line of your mock.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to perform unit test in a multi-thread context.

But I suggest you to read this [answer to another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159/how-should-i-unit-test-threaded-code/125487#125487). The `DRTestUtils` provides a few convenient methods to *hide* the `Thread.sleep` behind a nicer `waitForCondition` method call.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to implement using swing workers?

Also what you might want to try is if you are waiting then you might want to try and use `notify` or using a `synchronized` class.