# EasyMock unclear error: "expected: 1, actual: 1"

Tags: java, testing, easymock

I got fail of test with

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Expectation failure on verify:
    A.logon(null): expected: 1, actual: 1
    at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.verify(MocksControl.java:226)
    at org.easymock.EasyMock.verify(EasyMock.java:2080)
    at com.ATest.test
```

What this error means? Why it may happen? Please suggest.

Comment: Can you share the code that produces this error?

Comment: Please show your code. `"1" != 1` and sometimes `"1" != "1"`.

Comment: Please verify that the agruments you are specifying in the mock are same as the call to the mock. There would be one call to the mock but it may not match the exact specification you have provided to the expect call.

Comment: My test used multithreading classes which caused that error. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159/how-should-i-unit-test-threaded-code

Comment: @uditbansal is probably right. But a sample of the code and the full exception you receive would be helpful to confirm that :) Also, if you're expecting null, don't forget to use `EasyMock.isNull(MyClass.class)` in the expectation. You could receive a null Object (not a null MyClass) and it would throw this type of error.

Comment: EasyMock.makeThreadSafe may help in my case

Answer (score 4):

I had similar error. It turned out that the method was called on different thread. Making the method executing in the same thread solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the potential solution:

1. If your code is multithreading, try [How should I unit test threaded code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159/how-should-i-unit-test-threaded-code)
2. If you're using createStrictMock, you may want to make sure the method calls are in the correct order, otherwise it could return things like "expected: 1, actual: 1" or "expected: at least 0, actual: 1"

Answer (score 0):

what you see is just a result of `toString()` method called on both arguments. so in fact you may be doing any combination of:

```java
assertEquals(1L, 1);
assertEquals("1", 1);
assertEquals('1', 1);
assertEquals(customObject, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

### More code needed

We will need more code for a definitive answer so until that happens this is my best guess.

### Create a mock of your class

You have class `A` mocked somewhere in your test using [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock) or [EasyMock](http://easymock.org), something like:

```
A mockedA = EasyMock.createMock(A.class);
```

### Expect behaviour on mocked class

So all behaviour upon mocked class `A` that happens during your specific test (again missing code here) should be expected with:

```
final String someValue = "someValue";
EasyMock.expect(mockedA.logon(EasyMock.isA(String.class))).andReturn(someValue)
```

I'm totally guessing here on the signature of that `logon` method since I don't know your `A` class implementation. In my guess the `logon` method expects a `String` argument (can by any class or primitive really) and returns another `String` value.

### Matching

If you're matching for another argument, like argument of class `B` for example you need to update the above code to:

```
EasyMock.expect(mockedA.logon(EasyMock.isA(B.class))).andReturn(someValue)
```

Same can be said for the type of the return argument, if that is of type `C` just instance a `C` class object for `someValue` last param instead.

### Unclear errors

You have a valid point that the errors are very unclear in some cases. You are matching for something that accepted an argument object that was `null` in your test.

Now `null` can be matched in several ways, like just with fixed `null` value or with `EasyMock.isA(class)`. And that is likely where it went wrong in your test some experiment with the following:

```
EasyMock.expect(mockedA.logon(null)).andReturn(someValue)
EasyMock.expect(mockedA.logon(EasyMock.isA(SomeClass.class)).andReturn(someValue)
EasyMock.expect(mockedA.logon(EasyMock.isNull(SomeClass.class)).andReturn(someValue)
EasyMock.expect(mockedA.logon(aVariableHoldingNull)).andReturn(someValue)
EasyMock.expect(mockedA.logon(EasyMock.eq(aVariableHoldingNull)).andReturn(someValue)
EasyMock.expect(mockedA.logon(EasyMock.anyObject(SomeClass.class)).andReturn(someValue)
EasyMock.expect(mockedA.logon(EasyMock.isNull()).andReturn(someValue)
```

And this list is far from complete. Also make sure to get back to us with your solution so the community can learn from this.